# Umbraco 8 disable TidyEditorContent

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

i can disable TidyEditorContent in umbraco 8 to enable tag script?

Thanks in advance 
Davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TinyMce implementation in Umbraco 8 is a bit different from the old one in Umbraco 7. `TidyEditorContent` is no longer used and I would suggest that you look into customizing the TinyMce configuration in `config/tinyMceConfig.config`.

If you take a look at the `validElements` setting, I think you should be able to customize that to fit your needs. You may need to restart your site after changing this file for the changes to apply.

Comment: perfect! i'll modify this config, thanks a lot for your suggestion now it works fine.

Davide